# how to convert 2d byte[][] array (binary image array) to image java

Tags: java, arrays, image-processing, 2d

Hello I want to convert 2D byte[][] array to image.
I have converted black and white image to 2D byte[][] array and want to convert 2d byte array to image.

Comment: What does each item contain? RGB values?

Comment: I convert a black and white image to binary image and then convert to byte[][] array and each item contain 1 or 0

Comment: Is it a `BufferedImage`/`Image` object that you convert in the Java program, or do you do it with some other tool?

Comment: It was buffer image and then convert to byte[][] array in java

Comment: Do you convert each RGB-value to a binary value yourself? Then just run the code you use to convert RGB to binary "backwards", if that's possible. If you use a library, look for another method (function) to convert binary to RGB instead of the opposite, then use the code in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28460201/4170242) on the array of RGB pixel-data.

Answer (score -1):

### Converting the 2D-array to a 1D-array

To write a `byte`-array to a `BufferedImage`, it has to be (as far as I know) a one-dimensional array. You can convert the two-dimensional byte array (`byte[][]`) to a one-dimensional byte array (`byte[]`), by using these simple loops:

```
/*
 * Create a new 1-dimensional byte array which will hold the result
 * Set its size to the item count in the pixelData array
 */
byte[] oneDimArray = new byte[pixelData.length * pixelData[0].length];

/*
 * Loop through the "horizontal" row in the pixelData array
 */
for(int x = 0; x < pixelData.length; x++) {
    /*
     * Loop through each item in the current vertical row
     */
    for(int y = 0; y < pixelData[x].length; y++) {
        /*
         * Set each item in the 1-dimensional array to the corresponding
         * item in the 2-dimensional array
         */
        oneDimArray[x + y * pixelData.length] = twoDimArray[x][y];
    }
}
```

### Converting the byte-array to a BufferedImage

Now you can write the `byte`-array to a new `BufferedImage`, by using this simple code:

```
ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(oneDimArray);
BufferedImage finalImage = ImageIO.read(byteIn);
```

([Taken from here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-byte-to-bufferedimage-in-java/))

**Now** you can use the `BufferedImage` for whatever you want, and hopefully it will look like it did before the conversions.

Comment: `ImageIO` expects the bytes to be in a file format, not raw RGB pixels. Your last paragraph will not work.

Comment: Ah, but look at the link that I provided.

Comment: I did, so should you. :-) Quote: *"[the] following example will read an image file named “darksouls.jpg“, convert it into byte array, and then reuse the converted byte array..."*. The link you refer starts out with bytes in JPEG format, not raw pixels. That is why it works. But if you're in doubt, don't take my word for it. Try for yourself.

Comment: @haraldK Ah, sorry. I'll take a look at it